# Download message from Google group

Tags: google-groups

I need to download an archived google group.
Following link is one of the messages of that group for example.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.aeronautics/ViFtpXfVm7M

The problem is, what i see in the browser does not appear in the downloaded webpage.

With my very limited knowledge, It seems to me like the reason behind it is this content is dynamically created by java-script. Or else, these downloaded files are with so called 'mbox' extension which is encrypted ?

What I've tried so far

## First trys

1. Simple download
   wget https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sci.aeronautics/ViFtpXfVm7M
2. With mirror
   wget --mirror  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sci.aeronautics/ViFtpXfVm7M

## Assuming its encrypted

3. With cookies.
   wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sci.aeronautics/ViFtpXfVm7M
4. Got thunderbird to setup my gmail and opening. did not open correctly

## Assuming the content was javascript generated

5. Downloaded using phantomJS
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/411540/how-to-get-wget-to-download-exact-same-web-page-html-as-browser
6. Downloaded using phantomJS with a different script
   https://gist.github.com/giocomai/247d54e097b5083e2451

## Used scripts available from Github

7. https://github.com/henryk/gggd
8. https://github.com/icy/google-group-crawler

But none did not work so far.

Can anyone please shed some light on how to download this page with its message as a readable html or txt file ?

Cheers
AyyoSalli

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/sci.aeronautics/msgs/atom.xml?num=100 to get some of the posts - but it only gets roughly half the posts in this case. 
And it has all the messages from all topics together. 
View it in Firefox or Classic Opera to see directly in a more human-readable form.

But since you say you already got a file in standard mbox format, what exactly is wrong with it - did you attempt to import it into a locally installed email or newsclient ? (like Thunderbird)

Comment: Hi Matti, Thanks for the reply. I figured https://gitlab.com/mcepl/gg_scraper worked for my purpose. And the mbox could be imported to firefox with "Export Import Plugin" Thanks heaps for the help